# Pre-req Postman Variables Stopped Working

Tags: postman-pre-request-script

I have an incredibly simple pre-request script that was working just fine on my Mac using the lastest Postman.  I was sharing the workspace and Postman was constantly nagging me about not paying, and my sharing partner wasn't looking at the work so I turned off sharing.  That took out quite a bit of my work unexpectedly and I had to rebuild many queries.   My queries are working now, however, my super simple script isn't.  My sole variable is no longer being populated.  The code is the same that was working until I deleted the sharing profile.  Any ideas?

```
var moment = require('moment');
pm.collectionVariables.set = ("onehourago", moment().subtract(60,'minutes').unix());
```

{{onehourago}} is an unresolved variable.  What gives?

Thank you, from a novice.

Answer (score 0):

Careless idiots should not waste others time. = sign?  Really?  Delete that and Postman works just fine.

pm.collectionVariables.set ("onehourago",moment().subtract(60,'minutes').unix());